# Spring JTA transaction with JPA and jndi datasource for Websphere

Tags: spring, jta

I am having multiple datasource and one one database configured with JPA. I am using websphere 7. I want all these datasouces to be configured as global transactions. I am using below spring configurations but the transactions are not working as expected global transaction. If one db is failing then the other db is getting commited which is not expected as single global transactions. Can you please help me where i m doing incorrect,

I am having 2 datasouce one as configured below with id="us_icfs_datasource" and another using JPA

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/persistenceUnit"/> 
    <bean id="pabpp" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<!-- Needed for @Transactional annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="US_ICFS_DATASORCE" 
        jndi-name="jdbc/financing_tools_docgen_txtmgr"
        cache="true"
        resource-ref="true"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

also I have added below code in web.xml

```
 <persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/persistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>persistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-unit-ref> 

  <persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/persistenceUnit</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>persistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-context-ref>
```

below is my code where i m using transaction

```
> @Transactional    public TemplateMapping addTemplateMapping(User user,
> TemplateMapping templateMapping)          throws
> TemplateMappingServiceException {         .... }
```

Answer (score 4):

On Websphere you should use this bean to hook into the Websphere transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
     class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
```

See also this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html)

EDIT:

In order to use 2-phase commit (i.e. ensuring consistency across multiple resources), you will need to use XA data sources.  See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0407_woolf/0407_woolf.html) for details.

Comment: Also can we have two different transaction manager one with name transactionManager and another with name wsTransactionManager, so that only one of my bean use wsTransactionManager and rest automatically takes transactionManager

Comment: Why would you want to use two different txn manager beans?  In the end, the Websphere txn manager would be used regardless whether you use the `JTATransactionManager` or the `WebSphereUowTransactionManager`, the UOW bean just allows you to better use websphere features under the hood...

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for solution to change to WebshphereUowTransactionManager, but if i change to websphereuowtransactionmanger, I still dont get rollbacks as expected. One database is commiting eventhough my exception is returned from second database. Below is my code

Comment: In order to use a two-phase commit, you will need to ensure that both data sources are set up as XA data sources in websphere (see also the link that I've added in my answer).  If you want to add code, I would edit the question above.

Comment: yes. It would be good if you provide some sniplet. Because if i use XADatasource then below code is not working...class JFFS00AStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
    public JFFS00AStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource, String spName) {
        super(dataSource, spName);.....}  here Spring StoredProcedure class can only use Datasource not XADataSource

Comment: yes please, a question on SO should always be self-contained rather than spanning multiple topics.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your data sources that participate in global transaction must be of javax.sql.XADataSource type.

You also have to set transaction type in your persistence unit to JTA (not RESOURCE_LOCAL).

And you need to inform your JPA implementation that you want to do global transactions.

Comment: How do i do this, And you need to inform your JPA implementation that you want to do global transactions.? and If i change below to XA Datasource then my spring based Stored Procedure are not working <jee:jndi-lookup id="US_ICFS_DATASORCE" 
        jndi-name="jdbc/financing_tools_docgen_txtmgr"
        cache="true"
        resource-ref="true"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

Comment: What JPA implementation do you use?