# Websphere + Spring: javax.transaction.Transactional

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, websphere

Using Spring within Websphere, when using the `javax.transaction.Transactional`. Running the code locally or within Tomcat works as intended but while running within Websphere, it appears that the `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation is not resulting in a Transaction that includes the JPA-EntityManager. Replacing the `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation with the Spring version of `Transactional` solves this issue.

We would like to know what is required to fix this issue. I found this Stackoverflow-issue: [spring-jta-transaction-with-jpa-and-jndi-datasource-for-websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578061/spring-jta-transaction-with-jpa-and-jndi-datasource-for-websphere) which links to the Article: [0609_alcott-pdf.pdf](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott-pdf.pdf)

The advise given is to configure Spring to use the WebSphereUowTransactionManager as transaction manager.

The stackoverflow answer is from 2012. But since we are running a farely old WebSphere 7 version, it might sill be relevant to us.

Does anyone experienced the similar or a related problem?

**Update**

The following dependencies are used: 
spring-core: 4.3.9
hibernate.core: 4.2.15.Final
spring-boot starter: 1.5.4.RELEASE

Comment: Which Spring version are you using and how is the entity manager configured.

Comment: I updated the description to include the dependency. The configuration is nothing special. Only the plain @EnableTransactionManagement annotation might be of interest but nothing special here.